# While loop replacement in cypress

Tags: automation, cypress

How can I write something similar to the code below but without using the while statement? (I noticed that it doesn't work in cypress and takes a lot of memory and eventually crashes the compiler)

```
 const noAvailability = cy.contains('No time slots available. Please change interval or select another practitioner.')
        while (noAvailability) {
            cy.contains('Next week').click();
        }
```

Comment: Do you have a sample html of the calendar or a screenshot of the rendered html?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to adopt [cypress-recurse](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-recurse) for your case.
Sample usage from the repo:

```js
import { recurse } from 'cypress-recurse'

it('gets 7', () => {
  recurse(
    () => cy.task('randomNumber'),
    (n) => n === 7,
  )
})
```